# iOS: Scroll up to refresh

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios

Many iOS apps have a "scroll up to refresh" feature, such as the Twitter app. If you scroll up beyond the beginning of the page or table, you'll get a message explaining how to use the feature.

That controller is not from Apple but many apps seem to use it. I was told it was released for public use by a programmer, but I can't find it after a long google session.

I'd be grateful if anyone can direct me to it! Thanks!

Comment: The reason you couldn't find it was that it is called “pull*”, not “scroll*”. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a link to the original code by enormego on github:

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Answer (score 7):

This is a popular implementation: https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find two examples a few minutes after posting this question:

[How to make a Pull-To-Reload TableView just like Tweetie 2](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Also it was in Facebook's three20 library I guess.