# Scroll to load content in a UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm a bit of a noob to iOS development. I have been looking at a few apps (like **Twitter** and **Mobile RSS**) and they have this feature which loads more items from the internet when the `UITableView` is pulled up or down. For instance, let's say you are viewing the top boundary of a `UITableView`; when you pull the table view down an arrow pointing up will be revealed. As you release the view, new content will be loaded depending the speed at which you release the view... I don't know whether that makes any sense at all...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: same question  was already asked several hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247166/ios-scroll-up-to-refresh

Answer (score 0):

This code originated in Tweetie 2, created by Enormego. They've open sourced the code to this github repository: https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh.

Answer (score 0):

lets firstly say that it's not a iOS native UI feature.

the feature you're looking for is also inside three20 (it is an opensource library for iOs made by facebook guys) google for it.

NOTE: it's quite a big library.