# Scroll to load other content in a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit

I'm a bit of a noob to iOS development.  I have been looking at a few apps (like Twitter and Mobile RSS) and they have this feature which loads more items from the internet when the UITableView is pulled up or down.  For instance, let's say you are viewing the top boundary of a UITableView; when you pull the table view down an arrow pointing up will be revealed.  As you release the view, new content will be loaded depending the speed at which you release the view...  I don't know whether that makes any sense at all...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should be on StackOverflow. Also, the behaviour you're thinking about was pioneered by the Twitter app (née Tweetie).

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: Scroll up to refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247166/ios-scroll-up-to-refresh)

Answer (score 1):

Popular implementation here: https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh